# JDBCTemplate queryForMap compare and replace value in extracted lines

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, spring-jdbc

Can you help me to understand why my code doesn't work, please?

I am trying to get values from 2 columns from my database and store them in a hashmap where K_PARAM is my key and L_PARAM is my value. Then I would like to compare 2 characters from a line that I am extracting and see if these 2 characters are equals to my key or not. In case they are equals, I replace *key* with *value*.

Thanks in advance. This is the code :

```
if (action.equals("RP")) {
      if (marqueCarte = null) {
    jdbcTemplate.query(" select K_PARAM, L_PARAM from DLCOA.DLC_ADM_PARAMS where K_CHX_PARAM = '50'", new ResultSetExtractor<Map>(){
    @Override
    public Map extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,DataAccessException {
         HashMap<String,String> marqueCarte = new HashMap<String,String>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                  marqueCarte.put(rs.getString("K_PARAM"),rs.getString("L_PARAM"));

                  if (line.contains("blocE")) {
                      if (line.substring(line.indexOf("blocE") + 15, line.indexOf("blocE") + 15 + (line.substring(line.indexOf("blocE")+15)).indexOf("#")).equals(rs.getString("K_PARAM"))){
                         line = line.replace(line.substring(line.indexOf("blocE") + 15, line.indexOf("blocE") + 15 + (line.substring(line.indexOf("blocE")+15)).indexOf("#")),rs.getString("L_PARAM") );
                      }
                  }
            }

            return marqueCarte;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? You should be more specific. Your replacing code is hard to understand. If there is some kind of pattern you can use regex, at least to simplify and clarify your code.

Comment: in fact the probleme is with the hashmap and the methode after the override  it's like if java does't reconize my constructor, this is in my dataprocessor i parse a line then i replace 2 caractere with the value from hashmap

Comment: You have two problems then: (1) data is in the DB but is not been stored in your hashmap and (2) the replacement is not working either. I think that you're trying to do something like this **********blocE*****KEY******   -> **********blocE*****VALUE****** and that this can be achieved in a more efficient way. You should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: That is exactly what i want to do, do you have any suggestion for me !

Comment: Formatting your code, I've noticed that you got a typo here `marqueCarte = null` That way you are assigning marqueCarte the value null. I think that you are trying to compare in that condition. It should be `marqueCarte == null`. If you got that expression in another point in your code maybe you're "nullyfing" the results obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a more readable and modifiable solution for your second problem.
(I'm still not sure what's your first one)

Using regex and patterns you can achieve the replacement you want.

Let's assume that you are searching for the text "blocE" followed by 15 characters, followed at the same time by the text contained in `rs.getString("K_PARAM")` plus an "#"

We can model what you search as a pattern like this

```
"(blocE)(.{15})(" + key + "#)"
```

Parenthesis allow us to establish different groups in the regex.

```
 Group 1 - blocE
 Group 2 - 15 characters
 Group 3 - key + #
```

Being group 0 the complete matching expression.

Knowing this you can do the replacement applying the following code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String key = "KEY";         // rs.getString("K_PARAM")
        String value = "VALUE";     // rs.getString("L_PARAM")

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(blocE)(.{15})(" + key + "#)");

        String input ="helloworldblocE111111111111111KEY#blocE111111111111111KEY";

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

        if (m.find()) {
            String text2replace = m.group(0);
            String replacement  = m.group(1) + m.group(2) + value;
            System.out.println(input.replaceFirst(text2replace, replacement));              
        }
    }
}
```

If your pattern changes, you only have to change one line and you do not have to worry about such quantity of `indexOf`.